# Desde SQL como puedo hacer suma de ventas y calcular porcentaje de ganancia

Tags: mysql, sql

Teniendo la siguiente instrucción SQL. Pueden ignorar el WHERE (lo traigo desde PHP)

```
SELECT
    id_usuario,
    valor_servicio,
    porcentaje_empresa,
    fecha_servicio
FROM
    `tbl_servicios`
WHERE
    fecha_servicio LIKE '2022-11-10%'
```

Me muestra los siguientes datos:

[image: tabla sin filtros]

**Importante**

Como pueden ver, la columna `porcentaje_empresa` tiene diferentes valores. Por ejemplo, para el usuario 2 podríamos decir que:

[image: fila usuario 2]

Su primer venta fue de $12.000, menos 50%, quiere decir que se lleva $6.000 él y $6.000 la empresa.

Su segunda venta fue de $100.000, menos 60%, quiere decir que se lleva $40.000 él y $60.000 la empresa.

```
Venta1 = 12.000 - 50% = 6.000
Venta2 = 10.0000 - 60% = 40.000
Total Empleado = 46.000
Total Empresa = 66.000
```

**La pregunta es**

¿Cómo puedo hacer este cálculo desde SQL? Porque si empiezo a sumar ventas por usuario, **luego los porcentajes van a ser diferentes:**

```
SELECT
    id_usuario,
    SUM(valor_servicio) AS total_ventas,
    porcentaje_empresa,
    fecha_servicio
FROM
    `tbl_servicios`
WHERE
    fecha_servicio LIKE '2022-11-10%'
GROUP BY
    id_usuario
```

[image: tabla ventas totales]

Porque NO puedo, al usuario 2, aplicarle sobre `$30.000` el `50%`. Esto me generaría un valor ERRADO.

¿Tendría entonces que primero restar el porcentaje a cada venta, y luego sumar ese resultado de cada usuario? Quiero hacerlo todo desde SQL (mySQL), si es posible.

El resultado esperado sería tal que así:

[image: resultado esperado]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tienes que ocupar 2 select, en el select del fondo realizas los cálculos. Y en el último agrupas

```
SELECT 
   A.id_usuario, 
   A.SUM(ganancias) as ganancias, 
   A.SUM(empresa) as empresa,
   A.fecha_servicio
   FROM (
     SELECT 
        id_usuario, 
        valor_servicio * (100 - porcentaje_empresa) / 100 as ganancias,
        valor_servicio * porcentaje_empresa / 100 as empresa,
        fecha_servicio
     FROM tbl_servicios WHERE fecha_servicio LIKE '2022-11-10%') as A
group by id_usuario
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, me sale el siguiente error dentro de mysql: Cada tabla derivada debe tener su propio alias

Comment: Las lineas 3 y 4 (ganancias y empresa) es el nombre que le das luego con el segundo select?

Comment: @EMCode Agrégale un ALIAS al primer SELECT, antes del GROUP BY

Comment: Agregado con alias. @EMCode Si claro, son los nombres para el 2do select